# Java Regular Expressions - Matching the First Occurrence of a Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I'm matching URLs against a regular expression, testing if they reflect a "shutdown" command.

Here's a URL that performs a shutdown:

```
/exec?debug=true&command=shutdown&f=0
```

Here's another, legitimate but confusing URL that performs shutdown:

```
/exec?commando=yes&zcommand=34&command=shutdown&p
```

Now, I must ensure there's only one **command=...** parameter and it is **command=shutdown**. Alternatively, I can live with ensuring the *first* **command=...** parameter is **command=shutdown**.

Here's my test for the requested regular expression:

```
/exec?version=0.4&command=shutdown&out=JSON&zcommand=1
```

Should match

```
/exec?version=0.4&command=startup&out=JSON&zcommand=1&commando=shutdown
```

Should fail to match

```
/exec?command=shutdown&out=JSON
```

Should match

```
/exec?version=0.4&command=admin&out=JSON&zcommand=1&command=shutdown
```

Should fail to match

Here's my baseline - a regular expression that passes the above tests - all but the last one:

```
^/exec?(.*\&)*command=shutdown(\&.*)*$
```

The problem is with the occurrence of more than one command=..., where the first one is not shutdown.

I tried using lookbehind:

```
^/exec?(.*\&)*(?<!(\&|\?)command=.*)command=shutdown(\&.*)*$
```

But I'm getting:

```
Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 31
```

I even tried atomic grouping. To no avail. I can't make the following expression NOT match:

```
/exec?version=0.4&command=admin&out=JSON&zcommand=1&command=shutdown
```

Can anyone help with a regular expression that passes all the tests?

### Clarifications

I see I owe you some context.

My task is to configure a Filter that guards the entrance of all our system’s servlets, and verifies there’s an open HTTP session (in other words: that a successful Login has occurred). The filter also allows configuring which URLs do not require login.

Some exceptions are easy: /login does not need login. Calls to localhost do not need login.

But sometimes it gets complicated. Like the shutdown command that cannot require login while other commands can and should (the strange reason for that is out of the scope of my question).

Since it’s a security matter, I can’t allow users to merely append &command=shutdown to a URL and bypass the filter.

So I really need a regular expression, or otherwise I’ll need to redefine the configuration specs.

Comment: this isn't a great use case for regular expressions, just plain parsing with `.split()` and applying logic to it would be a much better choice!

Comment: If you know that the command=shutdown will always be the last one out of all commands, you could capture the first command value matched and check that it's "shutdown". That would be simpler, and it would be a lot clearer what your code should be doing. In other words I'm mostly corroborating with @JarrodRoberson! :P

Comment: You seem to be dealing with URIs, as such most frameworks are likely to provide you with a `Map<String, List<String>>` of query parameters or something equivalent. If you're not using one, you should probably do something like that yourself using `split` as suggested above before moving on to any business logic.

Comment: *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.* -- Jamie Zawinski

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to use regular expressions for this? Have you considered using a function that parses the URI and then examines the result of the parsing? Parsing a URI is a well known problem with ready-made solutions.

Comment: I'll add some clarifications to the question above.

Comment: The clarifications, point and farther and farther away from a regular expression solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tested (and fully commented) regex solution meets all your requirements:

```java
import java.util.regex.*;
public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern re = Pattern.compile(
            "  # Match URI having command=shutdown query variable value. \n" +
            "  ^                          # Anchor to start of string.   \n" +
            "  (?:[^:/?\\#\\s]+:)?        # URI scheme (Optional).       \n" +
            "  (?://[^/?\\#\\s]*)?        # URI authority (Optional).    \n" +
            "  [^?\\#\\s]*                # URI path.                    \n" +
            "  \\?                        # Literal start of URI query.  \n" +
            "    # Match var=value pairs preceding 'command=xxx'.        \n" +
            "  (?:                        # Zero or more 'var=values'    \n" +
            "    (?!command=)             # only if not-'command=xxx'.   \n" +
            "    [^&\\#\\s]*              # Next var=value.              \n" +
            "    &                        # var=value separator.         \n" +
            "  )*                         # Zero or more 'var=values'    \n" +
            "  command=shutdown           # variable and value to match. \n" +
            "    # Match var=value pairs following 'command=shutdown'.   \n" +
            "  (?:                        # Zero or more 'var=values'    \n" +
            "    &                        # var=value separator.         \n" +
            "    (?!command=)             # only if not-'command=xxx'.   \n" +
            "    [^&\\#\\s]*              # Next var=value.              \n" +
            "  )*                         # Zero or more 'var=values'    \n" +
            "  (?:\\#\\S*)?               # URI fragment (Optional).     \n" +
            "  $                          # Anchor to end of string.", 
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.COMMENTS);
        String s = "/exec?version=0.4&command=shutdown&out=JSON&zcommand=1";
            // Should match
//      String s = "/exec?version=0.4&command=startup&out=JSON&zcommand=1&commando=shutdown";
            // Should fail to match 
//      String s = "/exec?command=shutdown&out=JSON";
            // Should match
//      String s = "/exec?version=0.4&command=admin&out=JSON&zcommand=1&command=shutdown";
        // Should fail to match";
        Matcher m = re.matcher(s);
        if (m.find()) {
            // Successful match
            System.out.print("Match found.\n");
        } else {
            // Match attempt failed
            System.out.print("No match found.\n");
        } 
    }
}
```

The above regex matches any RFC3986 valid URI having any scheme, authority, path, query or fragment components, but it must have one (and only one) query `"command"` variable whose value must be exactly, but case insensitively: `"shutdown"`.

A carefully crafted complex regex is perfectly fine (and maintainable) to use when written with proper indentation and commented steps (like shown above). (For more information on using regex to validate a URI, see my article: [Regular Expression URI Validation](http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html))

Comment: Ah, I see. So instead of skipping over characters agnostically, this solution takes into account each group, ``&key=val``, but fails if it encounters ``command`` for a key, and only allows continuation if the val is ``shutdown``. Nice! +1

Comment: In a business environment, the first time this has to be maintained by an intern or junior programm and @ridgerunner isn't around to offer another solution in a quick few minutes, it will get deleted and re-written with a simple procedural check the way I suggested, and the person that let this get into a corporate code base will get chewed out completely. *Just because you can doesn't always mean you should!*

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson - My answer does not say it should be used. However, it does represent a correct solution to the OP's original question that is both accurate and efficient and correctly matches (and doesn't match) exactly what was requested. A down vote here seems a bit harsh and unfair.

Comment: there are apparently twice as many people that agree that this is **not** the appropriate answer to the question ... and if you read the other answers, the poster says they abandoned the regex route because it wasn't the right path as was suggested, just saying.

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson - And there are 100 times as many programmers who don't speak fluent regex than those who do - but that is not the point. The fact remains that this regex solution is 100% accurate, solves the problem neatly, and is likely far more efficient that any procedural solution. In a production environment, execution speed is frequently an important design criteria and this solution is _fast_. And for those of us who _do_ speak regex, this carefully crafted and thoroughly documented solution _is easily maintainable!_ Just because a technology is hard doesn't mean you shouldn't use it.

Comment: I have never seen a regex of any complexity that couldn't be hard coded procedurally and be many times faster than any given regular expression engine.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do it in ***multiple*** steps:

***(1)*** Find match of `^(?=\/exec\?).*?(?<=[?&])command=([^&]+)`

***(2)*** Check if match is `shutdown`

Comment: Agreed; there is no one-step regex solution to this, except maybe by the ridiculous alternation brute-forcing method (which would create an alternation of more than 2^16 cases to simulate a negative lookbehind for ``command=shutdown``).

Comment: @acheong87 - No, a single pass regex most certainly can be crafted that is both accurate and efficient. See my answer for an example. (No need for lookbehind.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I thank you all for your great answers! I tried some of the suggestions, struggled with others, and all in all I have to agree that even if the right regex exists, it looks terrible, non maintainable, and can serve well as a nasty university exercise, but not in a real system configuration.

I also realize that since a Filter is involved here, and the Filter already parses its own URI, it is absolutely ridiculous to glue back all the URI parts into a string and match it against a regular expression. What was I thinking??

I'll therefore redesign the Filter and its configuration.

Thanks a lot, people! I appreciate the help :)

Noam Rotem.

P.S. - why was I getting a userXXXX nick? Very strange...

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with just accepting the first match, you could just use `'\\Wcommand=([^&]+)` and fetch the first group.

Otherwise, you could just call `Matcher.find` twice to test for subsequent matches, and eventually use the first match, why do you want to do this with a single complex regex?

Answer (score 0):

If this can be done with a single regular expression, and it may well could be; it will be so complex as to be un-readable, and thus un-maintainable as the **intent** of the logic will be lost. Even if it is "documented" it will still be much less obvious to someone who just knows Java.

A much better approach would be to use the `URI` object parse the entire thing, domain and all and pull off the query parameters and then write a simple loop that walks through them and decides based on your business logic what is a shutdown and what isn't. Then it will be simple, self-documenting and probably more efficient ( not that that should be a concern ).

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Java coder, but try this one (works in Perl) >>

```
^(?=\/exec\?)(?:[^&]+(?<![?&]command)=[^&]+&)*(?<=[?&])command=shutdown(?:&|$)
```

Comment: Didn't work for me in Java... The syntax seems right, but it didn't even match the simple examples...

Answer (score 0):

To match the first occurrence of command=shutdown use this:

```
Pattern.compile("^((?!command=).)+command=shutdown.*$");
```

The results will look like this:

```
"/exec?version=0.4&command=shutdown&out=JSON&zcommand=1" => false
"/exec?command=shutdown&out=JSON" => true
"/exec?version=0.4&command=startup&out=JSON&zcommand=1&commando=shutdown" => false
"/exec?commando=yes&zcommand=34&command=shutdown&p" => false
```

If you want to match strings that ONLY contain one 'command=' use this:

```
Pattern.compile("^((?!command=).)+command=shutdown((?!command=).)+$");
```

Please note that using "not" qualifiers in regular expressions is not something they are intended for and performance might not be the best.

Comment: For some reason it didn't work for me. But it helped me realize I need to rethink the entire solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    "^/exec\\?(?:(?:(?!\\1)command=shutdown()|(?!command=)\\w+(?:=[^&]+)?)(?:&|$))+$\\1");
```

Or a little more readably:

```
^/exec\?
(?:
  (?:
    (?!\1)command=shutdown()
    |
    (?!command=)\w+(?:=[^&]+)?
  )
  (?:&|$)
)+$
\1
```

The main body of the regex is an alternation that matches either a shutdown command or a parameter whose name is not `command`.  If it does match a shutdown command, the empty group in that branch "captures" an empty string.  It doesn't need to consume anything, because we're only using it as a checkbox, confirming *en passant* that one of the parameters was a shutdown command.

The negative lookahead - `(?!\1)` - prevents it from matching two or more shutdown commands.  I don't know if that's really necessary, but it's a good opportunity to demonstrate (1) how to negate a "back-assertion", and (2) that a backreference can appear before the group it refers to in certain circumstances (what's known as a *forward reference*).

When the whole URL has been consumed, the backreference (`\1`) acts like a zero-width assertion.  If one of the parameters was `command=shutdown`, the backreference will succeed.  Otherwise it will fail even though it's only trying to match an empty string,  because the group it refers to didn't participate in the match.

But I have to concur with the other responders: when your regexes get this complicated, you should be thinking seriously about switching to a different approach.

---

**EDIT:**  It works for me.  Here's the **[demo](http://ideone.com/tJddy)**.

Comment: I couldn't get this regex to work... It looked like it should do the job, but it didn't. But I'm now realizing the regex becomes so nasty that I'd rather redefine the Filter specs and use code instead of regular expressions...